# Apply smoothing to scaled display object

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a display object (not image) that I'm scaling down. It has the same jaggies and aliased edges that an image does when it's scaled. Is there a way to smooth that display object in the same way the image is smoothed?

**Update**
This is an interactive display object (sprite) with interactive child display objects. I can't draw it to a bitmap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try forcing the display object into "3d" mode by adding a Matrix3D transform to it. The easiest way to do that is to simply give it a rotationX value:

```
myDisplayObject.rotationX = 0.0;
```

Comment: hmmm interesting. I didn't get what you were suggesting before. I will have to try it at work. Is there much difference in 3D mode? How is it different?

Comment: it tends to look smoother (or a bit blurrier depending on your taste) when scaling because it forces hardware acceleration (if supported), much in the same way as scaling a bitmap with a width and height that are powers of 2 results in taking advantage of mipmapping on the gfx card (if supported).

Answer (score 2):

You can also try checking the "hinting" box on your shapes (sometimes this makes circles & ovals get sort of strange shaped, so it's a gamble), and you can try selecting "Cache as bitmap" from the render dropdown.

Comment: I've used pixel hinting before to get better results. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Do bicubic resampling on the sprite with Pixel Blender?

http://blog.onthewings.net/2009/08/25/bicubic-resampling-by-pixel-bender/

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set the smoothed property of the bitmap object to true and than scale it:

[look here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Bitmap.html#smoothing)

You Display object must contain a Bitmap, or is the Bitmap itself...

Comment: In this case it is not a bitmap

Comment: I have added to my answer a way for you to create a bitmap from you displayObject!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting `stage.quality = stageQuality.High;`?
Also if you did that and you want to set the smoothing manually you can try the [Lanczos re-sampling function](http://wonderfl.net/c/dLf0) (I did not made it).

Warning: you don't want to use this function every frame since it's pretty performance heavy!

First you need to draw you displayObject to an Bitmap with BitmapData:

```
var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(dispObject.width, dispObject.height, true, 0);
//Create new bitmapData with the same size as your object and with transparancy.
bmd.draw(dispObject);
//Draw you displayObject onto the empty Bitmap
var b:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bmd, true);
//Create the bitmap container and load the data, and the true turns smoothing on!
addChild(b);
//Add it to the stage and now you can use the scale and width variables like this
b.x = dispObject.x;
b.y = dispObject.y;
b.scaleX = dispObject.scaleX;
b.scaleY = dispObject.scaleY;
```

Comment: I have tried setting the stage quality to high and also best but no changes.

Comment: Then if you really need I would recommend reading through the code of the sample I gave and try figuring it out that way!

Comment: It is an interactive display object with child objects. I can't draw it to a bitmap.

Comment: Can't you draw the child objects as bitmaps?

Comment: No, the child objects are interactive and moving as well so it is not an option.

Comment: Why not? As I've showed in my example you can move the bitmaps around!

Comment: It is a full application with text inputs and many other complex nested display objects. Drawing it to a bitmap is not an option.